# Inconsistent result fron functional test with protractor

Tags: protractor, sendkeys

I created functional tests with protractor, and I get inconsistent results. sendKeys (in Chrome) provides inconsistent results. Sometimes the test fails, and sometimes the exact same test works. How can I use sendKeys and get consistent results?

```
it('should add explanation', function() {
    browser.sleep(1000);
    topic.createExplanation();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    expect(topic.items.count()).eventually.equal(1);
});

it('should input text', function() {
    element(by.css('.item-form__heading>input')).sendKeys('testtitle');
    browser.sleep(3000);
    element(by.css('.redactor_placeholder')).sendKeys('testbody');
});
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you test AngularJS application you can use

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

instead of sleep

otherwise I recommend you to use browser.wait:

```
   browser.wait(function(){
       console.log("polling for a firstName to appear");
       return    browser.isElementPresent(by.name('firstName')).then(function(el){
             return el === true;
           });
   }).
   then(function(){
       somefunctionToExecute()
    });
```